# Site with many images, load only some images?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a site that show many images hosted in a server. In the page, the images are situated in  of max 100 images. In a single moment, only one div is displayed (throw the css style "display") and the others have the display:none.

I need a way that allow me to load only the images of the div displayed because when I open the site, it loads all the images.

Comment: You kinda need to specify how you want to load the images.  Sequentially, randomly based on user input, alphabetically,... Also are they all the same size?  Should they render to the same location?  Each scenario would have a different optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

when You are using `display:none` - the images are still being downloaded. But if You'll use `display:none` on `background-image` they won't. Another approach is to make a button "Load more..." and asynchronously request the rest of the images

Comment: Thanks. And how i can do to asynchronously request the rest of the images? So on default no images are loaded, right?

Comment: ajax. For example - on button click make ajax call to the server and load portion of images or not by click but on scrolldown. Similar functionality you can see on instagram. "On default" load 10 images (it's much better than 100 at once) and then load another 10 by ajax in the right moment and it will be just fine

Answer (score 0):

your can hide the images which you dont want to display on page load, try following code in document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img1").hide();
    $("#img2").hide();
    $("#img3").hide();
           .
           .
           .
    $("#img_n").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm trying

Comment: I've tryed but, in the optional bar on mozilla, i see that the browser load also the image of the other div.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is by making a large image sprite, which you will upload and let the browser cache it.

A good explanation about CSS sprites can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the img tag's `src=""` blank on all but the first image and modify it with javascript.
You can use an onload event to trigger setting the next src property.